# Can I load different RAILS_ENV for different pow host for one app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rack-pow

I want to run my capybara-webkit-enabled acceptance tests through Pow. Our app has several subdomains, and it's a pain getting it to work. If I run my tests through pow, though, they work. Only problem is I have to edit my .powenv and restart pow to run my tests, and then same deal to go back to the dev env.

My goal now is to have appname.dev go to my app with the development environment loaded, and appname.test go to the same app with test environment.

Is this possible with pow?

I can set up appname.dev and appname.test (http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_3.1), but they both read the same .powenv, and thus start with the same RAILS_ENV.

Comment: There's only one Pow process, and it looks like it's handing requests to both .dev and .test to the same worker.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954945/is-it-possible-to-use-the-powrc-file-to-pass-session-variables-to-rails-based-o), and its two answers might be useful for your issue.

I think the core answer is that this is done mainly within Rails, as opposed to within Pow. You'd have your Rails app determine the hostname being accessed, and then behave accordingly ... The only place that Pow steps in is the actual serving of different hostnames for the same Rails app (so, multiple symlinks in `~/.pow` that all point to the same Rails app).

The question (and its two answers, and the blog post that's linked from there) handle this on the domain site, not the tld side ... So the examples will be closer to using `app-testing.dev` and `app-development.dev` than using `app.dev` and `app.test`. It might be possible to accomplish the same thing with the tld, but I haven't worked that out yet.