# Is it possible to use the .powrc file to pass session variables to Rails based on the URL being accessed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-pow

I have a Rails 2 app that serves multiple domains. That is, http://domainA.com and http://domainB.com are both served by the same Rails app. When I launch these manually, I specify which site I want to see by passing a `site` variable: `site=domainB ruby script/server`.

I'd like to use Pow so that I can access both sites via http://domainA.myapp.dev and http://domainB.myapp.dev (I'd also be happy with http://domainA.dev and http://domainB.dev if that's easier).

I can do this manually by adding `export site="domainB"` to my `.powrc` file, and editing that by hand (then doing `touch tmp/restart.txt`) each time I want to switch sites ... I'd prefer something a bit more automatic, though. I'm thinking something like the equivalent of `subdomain == domainA ? export site="domainA" : export site="domainB"` within the `.powrc` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this, and wrote a blog post about it [here](http://www.commonmediainc.com/blog/how-serve-multi-site-rails-apps-and-use-pow-make-it-easy).  This is the gist of how it's done...

I configured my `before_filter` to get the domain that's being accessed, and to use that throughout the Rails app. If the site is being accessed via the standard Rails app, it won't have a domain (it would just be `localhost`). In that case, the `before_filter` looks for the `site` variable being passed at the command line (and if that's not passed, then it uses a default site).

```
def set_site
  if RAILS_ENV == "development"
    session[:site] = case request.domain
      when "domainA.dev" then "domainA"
      when "domainB.dev" then "domainB"
      else ENV['site'] || "domainA"
    end
  else session[:site].blank?
    if RAILS_ENV == "staging"
      session[:site] = case request.subdomains.last # *.yourstagingdomain.com
        when "domainA" then "domainA"
        when "domainB" then "domainB"
      end
    elsif RAILS_ENV == "production"
      session[:site] = case request.domain
        when "domainA.com" then "domainA"
        when "domainB.com" then "domainB"
        else "domainA"
      end
    else
      session[:site] = "domainA" # default
    end
  end
  if @site.nil?
    @site ||= Site.find_by_name(session[:site])
  end
end
```

The whole thing is actually done within Rails itself, and the only involvement that Pow has is that there has to be a symlink for each site being served by the Rails app.

The symlinks must also match the `request.domain` that's being checked in the `before_filter`. So, in this example there would be two symlinks - `domainA` and `domainB`.

Answer (score 0):

I've written the following rake task to switch sites with `rake pow[SITENAME]` until I can find a more automated solution. This code is also available as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/2898018).

```
desc "Switches site that Pow serves"
task :pow, :site_name do |t, args|
  pow_config = "#{Rails.root}/.powrc"
  args.with_defaults(:site_name => "domainA")

  # Overwrite .powrc file with new site name
  file = File.open(pow_config, 'w')
  file.write "if [ -f \"$rvm_path/scripts/rvm\" ] && [ -f \".rvmrc\" ]; then
source \"$rvm_path/scripts/rvm\"
source \".rvmrc\"
fi

export site=#{args.site_name}"
  file.close

  # Restart Pow
  FileUtils.touch "#{Rails.root}/tmp/restart.txt"

  # Announce site change
  puts "Switched to #{args.site_name}"
end
```